# need help in converting object to array in typescript because of ngfor directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWKr0.jpg
at this link I have posted all the errors I got. i alredy tried doing JSON.parse on the response but that didn't solve the issue. basically i created a backened API in c# that communicates with an angular frontend for doing CRUD operations and I have a problem on figuring out how to convert the response the backend gives me to display it in my angular component because ngfor cant iterate objects. if someone can help me it would be higly appreciated thanks everyone.

THIS IS THE SERVICE

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 import{ NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
 export class EventiadminService {

 constructor(private http:HttpClient, private router:Router) { }


  Getallevents():Observable<any>{
   return 
 this.http.get("https://localhost:44338/api/Event/getalleventswithoutscore");
}

 Createevent(form:NgForm){
  const data=JSON.stringify(form.value);
   return this.http.post('https://localhost:44338/api/Event', data,{
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    })
  });
}

 Getsingleevent(idevent:any):Observable<any>{
   return 
   this.http.get("https://localhost:44338/api/Event/GetsingleEventbyid/"+idevent);
  }
}
```

THIS IS THE COMPONENT TS FILE

```
   @Component({
  selector: 'app-eventiadmin',
  templateUrl: './eventiadmin.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./eventiadmin.component.scss']
 })
export class EventiadminComponent implements OnInit {

  eventi:Array<any>=[];
  singleeventbyid:Array<any>=[];
  creaevento:Evento={
   categoria:'',
   datafine:'',
   datainizio:'',
   nomeevento:''
   };
    nomeevento='';
     categoria='';
     datafine='';
     datainizio='';

       idevent='';

     constructor(private eventiservice:EventiadminService, private 
                         http:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
 }

  Getallevents(){
   this.eventiservice.Getallevents().subscribe((data:any[])=>{
    console.log(data);
    this.eventi=data;
  })
 }

  Createevent(form:NgForm){
   this.eventiservice.Createevent(form).subscribe(e=>{
    console.log(e);
   });
  }

  Getsingleeventbyid(idevent){
   this.eventiservice.Getsingleevent(idevent).subscribe(se=>{
       console.log(se);
      this.singleeventbyid=se;
    });


  }
```

AND FINALLY HERE IT'S THE HTML

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                <form #getsingleevent="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="Getsingleeventbyid(idevent)">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control has-validation" placeholder="ID evento da cercare"  name="idevent" minlength="1" required [(ngModel)]="idevent" #idtemp="ngModel" name="idevent">
                    <div *ngIf="idtemp.invalid&&idtemp.dirty">
                        <div *ngIf="idtemp.errors.required"  class="invalid-feedback">Questo campo non può essere vuoto</div>
                        <div  *ngIf="idtemp.errors.minlength" class="invalid-feedback">l'id inserito è troppo breve</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bi bi-card-heading"></i>Ottieni singolo evento</button>
                    </div>
                </form> 
                <table class="table  table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID evento</th>
                            <th>Nome evento</th>
                            <th>Categoria</th>
                            <th>Data di inizio</th>
                            <th>Data di fine</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let eventoid of singleeventbyid" >
                            <td>{{eventoid.eventId}}</td>
                            <td>{{eventoid.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{eventoid.startingDate}}</td>
                            <td>{{eventoid.endingDate}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: You should provide the `console.log()` output of what you get from the API.

Comment: here it is you can see it in in the link with the images above

Comment: {eventId: 1, name: "sagra modificata", category: 1, startingDate: "2021-05-26T09:50:50.371", endingDate: "2021-05-27T09:50:50.371", …}
category: 1
endingDate: "2021-05-27T09:50:50.371"
eventId: 1
name: "sagra modificata"
scores: null
startingDate: "2021-05-26T09:50:50.371"
__proto__: Object

Comment: this is not enough to understand the full structure (need fuller snippet that shows two or more events), and also it would be better to add it to the question as code, with proper indentation...

Comment: its a get single how i'm supposed to have more events? the fuller snippet is there. i know it's that well indented but I provided a link to see everything you need. thank you

Comment: if it's a single event then why do you need `*ngFor`..?

Comment: because i dont properly know typescript and angular. and I'm serious that's why I need help in displaying the result of it in the component..

Comment: ok, i provided some code for you to try in an answer as it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need to handle an array of events, then just don't use `*ngFor`.

This should work:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{singleeventbyid.eventId}}</td>
    <td>{{singleeventbyid.name}}</td>
    <td>{{singleeventbyid.startingDate}}</td>
    <td>{{singleeventbyid.endingDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i'll try it thank you for the tip i'm a newbie that's why i asked here. thank you very much

Comment: the problem is that i don't have the properties above such as eventid and so on. that propertiess are the one i got in backend which used to work when doing calls with http client. so what can i create in typescript now in order to display the information in the component? thank you

Comment: in your screenshot's `console.log()` output it looks like such properties are returned from the backend...

Comment: yes that properties are from the backend. but on the angular side what should i create an interface? a class with that properties and then binding on them?. the only thing i need to pass to the backend is an id

Comment: From TypeScript perspective you can use an interface to represent an event. Using a class will be a bit more complicated because you would need extra code to initialize it with the values from the backend. From Angular perspective, I'm afraid I can't help much. I used angularjs before, but I'm not very familiar with Angular v2+. I switched to Vuejs...

Answer (score 0):

At first you don't need to JSON.parse the response handled by HttpClient. That is already done by HttpClient. You also dont need to JSON.stringify your request for the same reason.

NgFor directive is supposed to render items for each item in provided collection. It meant to iterate. So if you have an array of items then I see no reason why its not working.
But if you need to iterate through object you can use [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe for ngfor like this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of singleeventbyid | keyvalue">
  {{item.value}}
</div>
```

But, if I see it right way - your method name is get**single**eventbyid so answer provided by obe is more representational since you need to render a single entity.

Also an http error can be a case. But that will be another issue

EDIT:

An interface:

```
export interface ISingleEvent {
 eventId: string;
 name: string;
 startingDate: string;
 endingDate: string;
}
```

So u can change declaration from

```
singleeventbyid:Array<any>=[];
```

to

```
singleeventbyid: ISingleEvent; //in case if you recieving your responce as Object
singleeventbyid: ISingleEvent[]; //in case of array
```

Note, that type-checking in typescript is a kind of syntactic sugar. It is not required to have a type for anything to work.

Comment: Problem is I don't know how to do an interface in typescript. Can you provide me a snippet based on my actual code here? Thank you

Comment: I don't have http error in the http call. The call works fine. The problem is displaying the results in the component